# Fulltext search similar

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-search, search-engine

Lets say I want to query for string "this is first title" and I want it to return almost similar strings like below.

```
this is first title
this is second title
this is third title
```

Is this possible with `QueryOptions` to query for "almost similar" string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for `"this is" title` (enclosing the "this is" in double quotes treats it as a phrase), which should work for your particular use case.
If you're searching in a particular field, say 'summary', you can specify the field to narrow your search, e.g.: `summary:"this is" summary:title`

See also the answer to this question: [GAE Full Text Search API phrase matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523987/gae-full-text-search-api-phrase-matching/10647426#10647426) .
You can use the '~' operator to rewrite queries to include plurals, which is one way of searching for similar text.