# Stemming with GAE Full Text Search

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

In the new GAE API for Full Text Search, I can't find any option to activate stemming. I have tried to search for singular/plural words in my application, and indeed searching for "document" does not return the same result set as searching for "documents". Same goes for accentuated characters, searching for "vehicule" or "véhicule" does not return the same result set. 
Is there an option somewhere, either in the API or in the query language syntax, that I can use to activate stemming ? Or do I have to build my own stemming by pre-processing the query and translate for example "document" into "(document OR documents)" ?

Answer (score 0):

In [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523987/gae-full-text-search-api-phrase-matching) they discuss the same. You should use the now [documented](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Text_Parsing) ~ operator

Answer (score 0):

you should assume charset type.

Comment: Please expand your answer