# Google App Engine Java Text Search API doesn't work same as python in string search

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-search

I am trying to use Google App Engine Java Search API, but it doesn't work as intended. In fact python and java search differs.

Python:
[Website](http://gae-text-search.appspot.com/)
 
[Source Code](http://code.google.com/p/gae-text-search/source/browse/main.py)

Java:
[Website](http://gaecloudant.appspot.com/search)
[Source code](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/search/java/src/com/google/appengine/demos/search/TextSearchServlet.java)

When i search for "tes" python results in all documents with "test" but not java.
Is it a bug in java sdk, i am using 1.7.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is still not possible given the API.

See these posts for more information:

- [Partial matching GAE search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899083/partial-matching-gae-search-api/13171181)
- [GAE Full Text Search API phrase matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523987/gae-full-text-search-api-phrase-matching/)

This is also logged as an issue/defect here:

- http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7689